# String Manipulation within an Excel cell to build a list of substrings which match criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would normally have coded my output prior if I had direct access to the system. Unfortunately, my current customer how shall I say, slightly antiquated. I have been given a csvde dump from active directory.  Within Excel how I can extract all the 'CN=*,' values in cell A1 and list them into the adjacent cell A2?

| A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- |
| CN=Organization Management,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Discovery Management,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=test,DC=local;CN=VPN Users,OU=Groups,OU=TEST,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Debugger Users,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Wireless Users,OU=Groups,OU=TEST,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Exchange Public Folder Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=test,DC=local;CN=Exchange Organization Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=test,DC=local |  |

Comment: use FILTERXML if you have it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Comment: Unfortunately, FILTERXML is not available in Excel on the Mac, or in Excel Online. Which is another problem in its self

Comment: PowerQuery? Is that available in Mac?

Comment: @JvdV - tmk, no. PQ is not available to Mac either. frustrating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Excel 365 for Mac, you can do:

```
=LET( txt, A1,
        s, SEQUENCE(LEN(txt)),
        hdrSeq, (MID(txt,s,3)="CN=")*s, tlrSeq, (MID(txt,s,1)=",")*s,
        header, FILTER( hdrSeq, hdrSeq > 0 ), trailer, FILTER( tlrSeq, tlrSeq > 0 ),
        nxtTrlr, INDEX(trailer, IFERROR( XMATCH(header,trailer,1,-1), 1 ) ),
        MID( txt, header, nxtTrlr-header) )
```

where A1 contains the target text that you want to parse.

[image: result]

If you need it to spill right, this will do it:

```
=LET( txt, A1,
        s, SEQUENCE(LEN(txt)),
        hdrSeq, (MID(txt,s,3)="CN=")*s, tlrSeq, (MID(txt,s,1)=",")*s,
        header, FILTER( hdrSeq, hdrSeq > 0 ), trailer, FILTER( tlrSeq, tlrSeq > 0 ),
        nxtTrlr, INDEX(trailer, IFERROR( XMATCH(header,trailer,1,-1), 1 ) ),
        TRANSPOSE( MID( txt, header, nxtTrlr-header) ) )
```

[image: column-wise spill]

### Adding TEXTJOIN

> Note JvdV's answer within the comments - super sleek and non-intuitive.

If you need this as a single cell text, then:

```
=LET( txt, A1,
    s, SEQUENCE(LEN(txt)),
    hdrSeq, (MID(txt,s,3)="CN=")*s, tlrSeq, (MID(txt,s,1)=",")*s,
    header, FILTER( hdrSeq, hdrSeq > 0 ), trailer, FILTER( tlrSeq, tlrSeq > 0 ),
    nxtTrlr, INDEX(trailer, IFERROR( XMATCH(header,trailer,1,-1), 1 ) ),
    TEXTJOIN(",", 1, MID( txt, header, nxtTrlr-header) ) )
```

Comment: accidentally left C2 inside of the formula instead of referencing it via **txt**. that's fixed now.  If you need it to spill columnwise, wrap the last line **MID** in a TRANSPOSE.

Comment: Well done! My two cents (not worth another answer) `=LET(X,LEN(A1),Y,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",","),",",REPT(" ",X)),Z,TRIM(MID(Y,SEQUENCE(LEN(Y),,,X),X)),FILTER(Z,LEFT(Z,2)="CN"))`, which I think need to be still wrapped in a `TEXTJOIN()` for OP's needs.

Comment: Holy crap, @JvdV - that is a mind twist!  Excellent!  I did not note the TEXTJOIN need - perhaps I should add it, but it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a two-step solution useful:

1. use `TextToColumns` comand in `Data` tab to split string by semicolon, comma and equal signs:

[image]

2. use formula:

   `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,"CN="&FILTER(B1:ZZ1,A1:ZY1="cn"))`

[image]

Comment: I need to do this for 200 cells within a single column. if there an alternative single step?